# couldn't deduce template parameter of return type

Tags: c++, templates, factory

I am trying to create an abstract factory using std::function

A normal factory works fine, but when I want to return a factory (another std::function) instead of an object I get the following error:

```
/home/nikolai/Projects/cpplearn/AbstractFactoryPattern/Main.cpp:9:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘factoryProducer(const char [6])’
  auto shapeFactory = factoryProducer("shape")();
                                             ^
In file included from /home/nikolai/Projects/cpplearn/AbstractFactoryPattern/Main.cpp:3:
/home/nikolai/Projects/cpplearn/AbstractFactoryPattern/AbstractFactory.hpp:48:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class ReturnType> ReturnType abstractfactory::factoryProducer(const string&)’
 factoryProducer(const std::string& tag = {})
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/nikolai/Projects/cpplearn/AbstractFactoryPattern/AbstractFactory.hpp:48:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/nikolai/Projects/cpplearn/AbstractFactoryPattern/Main.cpp:9:45: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘ReturnType’
  auto shapeFactory = factoryProducer("shape")();
```

I defined Factory as follows:

```
namespace factory 
{

/**
 * A template for a factory, which is just a std::function.
 * See AnimalFactory.hpp for example usage.
 */
template <class ReturnType, class ...Args>
using Factory = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;

}
```

And the factory producers work fine except from the last one, where I'm trying to create a factory of factories and the return type must be dynamic:

```
namespace abstractfactory 
{

using ShapeFactory = factory::Factory<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>;
using ColorFactory = factory::Factory<std::unique_ptr<Color>>;

ShapeFactory shapeFactoryProducer(const std::string& tag = {})
{
    return [=]
    {
        if(tag == "rectangle")
            return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Rectangle());
        else if(tag == "circle")
            return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Circle());
        else if(tag == "square")
            return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Square());
        else
            return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(nullptr);
    };
}

ColorFactory colorFactoryProducer(const std::string& tag = {})
{
    return [=]
    {
        if(tag == "green")
            return std::unique_ptr<Color>(new Green());
        else if(tag == "blue")
            return std::unique_ptr<Color>(new Blue());
        else if(tag == "red")
            return std::unique_ptr<Color>(new Red());
        else
            return std::unique_ptr<Color>(nullptr);
    };
}

template <class ReturnType>
ReturnType
factoryProducer(const std::string& tag = {})
{
    return [=]
    {
        if(tag == "shape")
            return shapeFactoryProducer;
        else if(tag == "color")
            return colorFactoryProducer;
        else
            return [=] {};
    };
}

}
```

How can I achieve a dynamic return type for function `factoryProducer`?

EDIT: new code (still doesn't work):

```
struct FactoryType {};
struct ShapeType {};
struct ColorType {};

template <class TFactory, class ReturnType>
ReturnType factoryProducer(TFactory tag)
{
    return [=]
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, ShapeType>::value)
            return shapeFactoryProducer;
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, ColorType>::value)
            return colorFactoryProducer;
    };
}

auto shapeFactoryProducer = factoryProducer(ShapeType());
```

Comment: You can't achieve "a dynamic return type" in C++

Comment: @max66 the return type should be known at compile time based on the tag (don't know how to make the tag constexpr)

Comment: Does `tag` have to be a string?  If you can use an enum instead you could make it a template parameter.

Comment: @HenriMenkeI do not want the user to specify the return type explicitly.

Comment: Hang on. All you want to return is the lambda?

Comment: @J.Daniel - you got the point: you cant pass a `constexpr` as a simple function parameter (run-time known). You have to pass something known compile-time; usually a template value of some type. As suggested by Henry Menke, a `std::string` is a complication and, if you can, is better an enum or something (integer value? tag type?) that can be used as template parameter.

Comment: @max66 so if the tag is a template parameter the `ReturnType` can be deduced?

Comment: @J.Daniel - not that way but (1) using `if constexpr` inside the lambda (available starting from C++17) or (2) developing different `factoryProducer` (and different lambdas) for different tags, yes... should be possible.

Comment: @max66 ok so I'm using `if constexpr` together with `std::is_same` and I still get an error that the `ReturnType` cannot be deduced, I will post the code in the edit section. Can you point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you *know at compile time* you want a shape factory, why not just call `shapeFactoryProducer`?

Comment: @n.m. What I want is to determine the return type based on a tag

Comment: Why not just define a bunch of overloads (or template specializations)? `std::function<ShapeFactory (const std::string &)> factoryProducer(ShapeType) { return shapeFactoryProducer; }  std::function<ColorFactory (const std::string &)> factoryProducer(ColorType) { return colorFactoryProducer; }`

Comment: @melpomene yeah that works, thanks, but I tried the (1) that max66 was talking about. Doesn't seem to be possible or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @J.Daniel max66 was talking about template parameters. Your `tag` is not a template parameter.

Comment: If the tag is a compile-time constant, you can use it as a *template parameter* and dispatch on it. Values of regular function parameters cannot be used to determine the return type (unless you engage in heavy constexpr wizardry post-c++17). If the tag is *not* a compile-time constant, you cannot determine the return type based on it.

Comment: @melpomene I tried it also as template parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type deductuon syntax is way off mark. Here's the correct one (requires C++17).

```
template <class TFactory>
auto factoryProducer(TFactory tag)
{   
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, ShapeType>::value)
        return shapeFactoryProducer;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<TFactory, ColorType>::value)
        return colorFactoryProducer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is indeed what I wanted